# How to get placeholder text in HTML input in a scaffolded view by using Display(prompt) attribute over model class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, placeholder

I used **scaffolding to generate the views and controllers** for me and I am using the **EF code first syntax**.

I understand that T4 templates are responsible for implementing the attributes values in the generated HTML/view code, but I don't see the default scaffolding template available with `VS 2015 community edition` doing anything for placeholder text.

Per my understanding upon decorating a model property with `[Display(Prompt="some placeholder text")]` attribute results in the `some placeholder text` being displayed as placeholder for the input text box 
in the create/edit views.

But to my dismay, this does not happen.

Is there any other attribute? or something else I need to do? or is it because I used scaffolding to generate views? or is the default T4 template not doing its job very well?

My code for model class looks like below:

```
public class Status
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Status Name is needed!")]
    [Display(Name ="Status Name",Prompt ="Type something here!")]
    public string StatusName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the generated view code:

```
@model LunchFeedback.Models.Status

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Status</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StatusName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Edit:**

I am well aware that directly editing the view file and adding a placeholder holder there can do the job.

```
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StatusName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Type something here!" } })
```

But I want to control all things from the model and want to use scaffolding. Preferably even edit/customize T4 template to do so.

Comment: The `Prompt` property of `DisplayAttribute` and the value to the `ModelMetadata.Watermark` property. If is not used to generate a `placeholder=".."` attribute in a input.

Comment: @StephenMuecke and the default MVC template does not utilise the `ModelMetadata.Watermark` property when building the views?

Comment: No it doesn't. From [Brad Wilson's blog](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html) - _"Text that might be displayed as a watermark when editing this model in a text box. Default: null"_. It would seem reasonable to have used this property to generate the `placeholder` attribute, but I assume the MVC team just want this to be a bit more flexible and leave it to the developer to decide what to do with it (i.e when creating your own custom `EditorTemplates`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Prompt` property of `DisplayAttribute` add the value to the `WaterMark` property of the `ModelMetadata` associated with the property. It is not used for generating the html `placeholder` attribute.

You want to use its value as the `placeholder` attribute but another developer may want to use to generate a tooltip (using the `title` attribute) so its left up to the developer as to how they may want to use it.

The T4 templates for scaffolding edit view generate `@Html.Editor()` for properties of your model so you can create your own `EditorTemplates` in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder (or `/Views/youControllerName/EditorTemplates` if you want more specific templates to be used for a particular controller)

Note that the `EditorFor()` method searches for a template firstly in the `/Views/youControllerName/EditorTemplates`. If it does not find one, it then searches in the `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` and if one is not found, then it uses the default `EditorTemplate`

For example, to use a template for all properties which are typeof `string`, create a partial view named `String.cshtml` in the `EditorTemplates` folder

```
@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.ModelMetadata.Model, new { placeholder = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Watermark })
```

or to limit use of this template to just certain properties, name the partial (say) `PlaceHolder.cshtml` and then use the `UIHintAttribute` on your property

```
[Display(Name ="Status Name", Prompt ="Type something here!")]
[UIHint("PlaceHolder")]
public string StatusName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
public static class AppEditors
{
    public static MvcHtmlString AppTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>( this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, object htmlAttributes = null )
    {
        var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var placeholder = member.Member
                                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(Display), false)
                                .FirstOrDefault() as Display;

        var attributes = (IDictionary<string, object>)newRouteValueDictionary(htmlAttributes) ?? new RouteValueDictionary();

        if (placeholder!= null)
        {
            attributes.Add("placeholder", placeholder.Prompt);
        }
        return htmlHelper.TextBoxFor(expression, attributes);
    }
}
```

In View

```
 @AppEditors.AppTextBoxFor(Html,x => x.StatusName)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is really helpful. Creating custom extension for HTML helpers is also a good idea, but I would prefer to scaffold my views and would like to leverage the templates.